# Using C# or C++ how can you change a computer monitor's color and brightness settings?

Tags: c#, c++

How to change computers colour settings and screen brightness?

I'm creating an application and part of it I want to be able to click a button to change the screen brightness of your monitor.  I also want to be able to change the colour settings so I can flick from colour to black and white/grey scale.

I was originally going to use .NET but I really don't think that's possible at all.

I can't work out how to actually change a computers settings.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow! For screen brightness settings, I'll refer you to the following questions:

- [C# setting screen brightness Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194006/c-sharp-setting-screen-brightness-windows-7)
- [Adjust screen brightness using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013622/adjust-screen-brightness-using-c-sharp)
- [How to detect when screen brightness or system volume changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768259/how-to-detect-when-screen-brightness-or-system-volume-changed)

For color settings, once again we can use WMI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa394512 (prior to Vista, use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa394512)

Check out the `Monochrome` and `VideoMode` properties.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you. Appreciate it very much.